# having really strange issue in auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have table called `notifications` and i have `id auto_increment primary key`.

**Complete Table Structure.**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notifications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender_picture` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `message_link` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now problem is that auto_increment should insert record as below.

```
1 record
2 record
3 record
```

But its really strange why my `phpmyadmin` show me record as below.

```
1 record
3 record
2 record
```

Is there any `options` do i need to set in `phpmyadmin`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not a problem. Leave the records as is because those records are inserted randomly on the table.

Just do the ordering you desired during the projection (*SELECT statement*). eg,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLENAME 
ORDER  BY colName ASC // or DESC for descending
```

The clients will not look on the database but on the application you created `:D`

Comment: @DipeshParmar your comment isn't clear can you clarify/expand?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the phpmyadmin sorts the records by another field for display.